# tshark with --export-dicom gives “Segmentation fault (core dumped)”

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, docker-container, coredump, tshark

Scenario: I have two docker container: A(ubuntu) and B(debian). My host is a ubuntu server.

Container A sniff the traffic on the host and write pcap file on a mounted volume (bind). Container B access the same volume (mounted, bind) to extract object from pcap files.

When I run the tshark command `tshark -r pcapfile.pcap --export-objects "dicom, targetfolder"`  inside container B the output is "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

My best guess until now is that I have a permission problem although both containers are accessing the volume as root and changing the file permission also didn't help.

Am I on the wrong path? Is this error related to a permission problem? What I can do to make both containers share the same mounted volume on the host?

EDIT:
The bug has been fixed. Refer to  [Wireshark bug 16748](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16748).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I on the wrong path?

Yes.

> Is this error related to a permission problem?

No.

It's related to a bug in Wireshark; "tshark ... gives "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"" means "there is a bug in tshark".

Please report this as a bug on [the Wireshark Bugzilla](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/).

Comment: When I run the command on the host it works without any problem. Before adding a new bug to Wireshark I would like to understand how this is somehow related to docker container.

Comment: I mean, do you have any suggestion how to debug this?

Comment: "When I run the command on the host it works without any problem. Before adding a new bug to Wireshark I would like to understand how this is somehow related to docker container."  You're assuming it *is* related to running in a docker container.  It might be, for example, that some Wireshark preference setting on the host causes the buggy code in Wireshark not to be used, but that preference setting wasn't copied over to the docker container, so the buggy code *is* used.

Comment: "I mean, do you have any suggestion how to debug this?"  Find the core dump file, run the debugger (gdb) on the TShark executable and the core dump, and run the command "backtrace".  Then take the results of that and put it into a bug report, so the Wireshark developers configure out where their bug is.

Comment: Note that, as per [your Wireshark Q&A question](https://ask.wireshark.org/question/17911/tshark-run-in-a-docker-container-gives-segmentation-fault-core-dumped/), the version of TShark in the container is different fro the version on the host, so it may have nothing to do with running in a container or with a permissions problem, it may just be a bug in Wireshark 3.2.3 that's not in Wireshark 2.6.10.

Comment: I confirm that the problem is only with version 3.2, when I switch to version 2.6 and Ubuntu18.4 I don't have this bug anymore. Thanks for the support.

Comment: If you want to thank us for the support, *please* don't just say "older Wireshark, problem solved!" - get a stack trace, or supply a sample capture that causes the problem, and make a bug report, so we (the Wireshark developers) can try to *fix* the problem, so *other* users with 3.2 (who might not have the option of going back to 2.6 - or 3.0 if it doesn't have the bug) can get the fix as well.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Docker or permissions; it can be reproduced without Docker, as per [Wireshark bug 16748](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16748).

Comment: "as per [Wireshark bug 16748](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16748)." That bug is now fixed.